# How to move existing Django project template to React JS with Django Rest API

Tags: reactjs, django

I am having a Django project with approximately 200 methods in view and 40+ HTML templates; in this case, I don't want to move to Django Rest Framework to connect with React JS. Is there any way to migrate from the Django template to react UI without using the Rest framework? I also want to know to pass data from view to components.

Comment: Hey, have you seen this article: https://brainhub.eu/library/migrating-to-react/